# colab session killed with message tcmalloc: large alloc 1121959936 bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-colaboratory

I am trying to work a large dataset and my Colab session is stopped with this message

```
tcmalloc: large alloc 1121959936 bytes == 0x559fbd9d0000 @  0x7f52b62751e7 0x7f52b3e57cf1 0x7f52b3ebf171 0x7f52b3ebfc2b 0x7f52b3f54acc 0x559f1cff2fe5 0x559f1cfe8d0a 0x559f1cff05fe 0x559f1cfe8d0a 0x559f1cff05fe 0x559f1cfe8d0a 0x559f1cff05fe 0x559f1cfe8d0a 0x559f1cff05fe 0x559f1cfe8d0a 0x559f1cff05fe 0x559f1cfe8d0a 0x559f1cfef39d 0x559f1cfe8d0a 0x559f1cff05fe 0x559f1cfe8d0a 0x559f1d004619 0x559f1cfd477e 0x559f1d046b80 0x559f1cfc2026 0x7f52b5e72b97 0x559f1cfc1a2a
^C
```

But it is shown that my colab just used 6.82GB/12.72GB RAM on the top right corner of the Colab interface. What should I do with this error message? I have tried to call `!TCMALLOC_LARGE_ALLOC_REPORT_THRESHOLD=1200000000`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem?